# Casting integers and dates to strings in DQL

Tags: casting, dql

I need to filter the entities according to user's keyword. Say, user enters "12" and I need to find qall entities that have that "12" in defined text fields, IDs or dates.

At present I have expressions like this:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('entity')
   ->from('streets', 'street')
   ->join('street.zone', 'zone')
   ->join('zone.city', 'city')
   ->orWhere('LOWER(zone.name) LIKE :query')
   ->orWhere('LOWER(city.name) LIKE :query')
   ->orWhere('LOWER(street.name) LIKE :query')
   ->orWhere('street.id LIKE :query')
   ->orWhere('street.lastUpdated LIKE :query')
   ->setParameter('query', '%'.strtolower($searchQuery).'%')
;
```

I have no problem with strings but dates and integers cause type mismatch - the last two `orWhere`s cause errors. How to cast those integers and dates to strings inside DQL? I can't just do `->orWhere('street.id = :query')` because the user can enter "street" search term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any DQL keywords for this (you'd probably need custom Doctrine function) but it can be done other way. If you'd write:

```
    ->orWhere("CONCAT(street.id, '') LIKE :query")
    ->orWhere("CONCAT(street.lastUpdated, '') LIKE :query")
```

the cast to string will be done implicitly and there should be no problem using LIKE operator.